# Object properties being assigned to a form show up as object Object instead of the actual value

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks, formik

I'm passing an object called "team" to this function in React.  The "team" object has 4 different properties.

id, playerName, typeId, and locationName.

I am populating state values like this:

```
const [idValue, setIdValue] = React.useState(false);
const [typeIdValue, setTypeIdValue] = React.useState(false);
const [nameValue, setNameValue] = React.useState(false);
const [locationValue, setLocationValue] = React.useState(false);
```

And my function looks like this that sets the state values above.

```
const showEdit = (team) => {
        console.log(team);
        setShowRosterForm(true);
        setIdValue(team.id);
        setTypeIdValue(team.typeId);
        setNameValue(team.playerName);
        setLocationValue(team.locationName);
    }
```

I then display these values in a form like this:

```
const RosterForm = ({
                        idValue, typeIdValue, nameValue, locationValue
                    }) => ( ... display form fields )
```

But when I populate the form with these values, I just see [object Object].

But I don't understand that, because when I wite out the 'team' object to the console, I can see all the individual properties like id, typeId, playerName, and locationName.

So I'm not sure why it's an Object.

Is there a better way of going about doing this?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You do not need to pass in the state getters into your `RosterForm()`. Can you not directly use the getters `typeIdValue` and others to set the form?

Please print a `console.log(typeIdValue)` inside your `RosterForm()` so that you can see the value it receives.

I believe the setting of the values to the form might be incorrect. Could you update your code for setting the value to a field of your form?